# Gradle does not allow to add '-processor' java(1.8) compiler args

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Gradle does not allow me to add following compiler arguments using `options.compilerArgs` tag:

```
 compileJava {
    options.incremental = true
    options.fork = true
    options.failOnError = true
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.compilerArgs += [ "-processor com.company.apt.EngineProcessor", "-s /nvme/test/gradle_testing/project/engine/modules/engine/ejb/src"] 

}
```

Getting Following error while executing this command to build Java(1.8) project :

```
$ gradle clean build --no-build-cache
```

ERROR:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
javac: invalid flag: -processor com.company.apt.EngineProcessor
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler arguments with a space in them are quoted to preserve the space.

So you should be using:

```
options.compilerArgs += [ "-processor", "com.company.apt.EngineProcessor", "-s", "/nvme/test/gradle_testing/project/engine/modules/engine/ejb/src"]
```

A similar example can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:compilerArgs)